# Error al obtener respuesta desde PHP con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

tengo un problema con mi código y no consigo encontrar la solución por mas que busco. el caso que mi funcion de ajax me da un error cuando recibe la respuesta y dice que no existe. El error es "referenceError: data is not defined at eval"

dejo mi codigo  Ajax y el de PHP.

```
function deleteTask(id_table){
   var sendInfo = {
     table: id_table,

   };
   jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://localhost/Logistic/resources/deleteTable.php",
     success:function(datos){
       var datos2 = JSON.parse(datos);
       if (datos == "correcto") {
         location.reload(true);
       } else {
         alert("Cannot add to list !");
       }
     },

      data: sendInfo
      /*var id_list = $id;*/
   });



 }
```

código PHP.

```
<?php
  include("../resources/config.php");
  //session_start();

  $table = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['table']);
  echo $table;

  $consulta = "DELETE FROM tables WHERE id_table = '$table' ORDER BY 
  id_table LIMIT 1";
  $resultado2 =mysqli_query($db,$consulta)or die('Error. 
  '.mysqli_error($db));



  if ($resultado2 == true) {
   echo json_encode("correcto");
  }else{
   echo json_encode("no correcto");
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: El parámetro `data`  tiene que estar dentro de la petición Ajax, pero lo tienes fuera, prueba a moverlo de sitio, poniéndolo después de la `url`, algo así: `type: "POST",
     url: "http://localhost/Logistic/resources/deleteTable.php",
    data: sendInfo,`

Answer (score 0):

Yo pondria en JS asi.

```
function deleteTask(id_table) {
var sendInfo = {
    table: id_table,

};
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/Logistic/resources/deleteTable.php",
    data: sendInfo,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (datos) {
        //var datos2 = JSON.parse(datos);
        if (datos.correcto) {
            location.reload(true);
        } else {
            alert("Cannot add to list !");
        }
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
    },
});

}
```

y el PHP pondria asi.

```
 <?php
  include("../resources/config.php");
  //session_start();
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $table = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['table']);
  echo $table;

  $consulta = "DELETE FROM tables WHERE id_table = '$table' ORDER BY 
  id_table LIMIT 1";
  $resultado2 =mysqli_query($db,$consulta)or die('Error. 
  '.mysqli_error($db));

  $devolver = array(
      'correcto' => FALSE
  );

  if ($resultado2==TRUE) {
   $devolver['correcto'] = TRUE;
  }
  json_encode($devolver);


 ?>
```

Comment: lo puse como tu me indicas y nada sigue fallando con el mismo error